# .NET MVC relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to wrap my head around relationships and and I hoping someone can clarify this for me.

I have the following two models

```
public class dsExpressionOfInterest
{
    public int dsExpressionOfInterestID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual dsRegistration dsRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class dsRegistration
{
    public int dsRegistrationID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Expression Of Interest ID")]
    public int dsExpressionOfInterestID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "SLA Received")]
    public bool SLAReceived { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Received")]
    public DateTime? SLAReceivedDate { get; set; }
}
```

On the Index View of dsRegistration I would like to be able to display the CustomerName field from dsExpressionOfInterest, however this is not available to me.

How should my navigational properties be set in order to facilitate this?

**UPDATE**

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var dsregistration = db.dsRegistration.Include(d => d.Employee).Where(d => d.PackSent == false);

    return View(dsregistration);
}
```

There are other additional fields which I have not shown in the above models in order to simplify the problem.

Comment: How are you loading the initial object? Your navigation properties look correct, but you might not be using .include() when you are getting the dsRegistration object.

Comment: @sdm350 I am unable to include dsRegisterOfInterest as it is not available to me due to the navigation properties

Comment: You should show your controller code that shows how you're retrieving the objects to pass to the view.

Comment: Is this a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: @sdm350 yes it is a one-to-one relationship but with a primary key and a foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is a one-to-one relationship, [it is setup wrong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).

I'm assuming that each Registration has exactly one ExpressionOfInterest, and each ExpressionOfInterest has exactly one Registration.

In order to have one-to-one relationships in MVC4, the primary key of the child must ALSO be the foreign key. The relationship should look like this:

```
public class dsRegistration
{
    public int dsRegistrationID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "SLA Received")]
    public bool SLAReceived { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Received")]
    public DateTime? SLAReceivedDate { get; set; }

    //Indicate that a dsRegistration has an expresison of interest
    public dsExpressionOfInterest expressionOfInterest { get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class dsExpressionOfInterest
{
    //Foreign key
    [Key, ForeignKey("dsRegistration")]
    public int dsExpressionOfInterestID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual dsRegistration dsRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

and now in your controller you should be able to use

```
var dsregistration = db.dsRegistration.Include("dsExpressionOfInterest").Where(d => d.PackSent == false);
```

finally, in the view you should be able to access registration.expressionOfInterest.CustomerName

Comment: Many thanks. This allows me to access CustomerName in the view, however, I receive the following error when migrating the Database - Error: The new name 'dsExpressionOfInterestID' is already in use as a COLUMN name and would cause a duplicate that is not permitted.

Comment: I'll edit my post, and this may be unrelated, but you can remove dsExpressionOfInterestID from the dsRegistration class. Other than that I'm not sure what that might be, migrations can be a pain :-/

Comment: ok, but is that not my link between the two tables or is EF doing that in the background?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly store the ID in the mode, the expressionOfInterest link will tell EF to do that.

Comment: Ok I have removed it but I am still getting the same error. Thanks for getting me this far

Comment: I've removed all the navigation properties and Migrated the Database. This all worked fine. I then added @sdm350 changes and I am now getting the following error when I try the migration - The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.dsExpressionOfInterest_dbo.dsRegistration_dsExpressionOfInterestID". The conflict occurred in database "ConnectDB", table "dbo.dsRegistration", column 'dsRegistrationID'.

Comment: If you can it might be better to delete the database and allow EF to recreate it, as the foreign key was incorrectly setup before it might be a conflict because there is already data in the table.

Comment: That's it! Just deleted the test data I had in both tables and reseeded them. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Make a ViewModel that is different from your usual domain model. The ViewModel should  contain the fields needed for the view. You probably will have a different ViewModel for each action. For example, if the action is named Index:

```
public class RegistrationIndexViewModel
{
    public int dsRegistrationID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Expression Of Interest ID")]
    public int dsExpressionOfInterestID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "SLA Received")]
    public bool SLAReceived { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Received")]
    public DateTime? SLAReceivedDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

You pass the view model to the dsRegistration view instead of the domain model. The domain models work with the database and enforce the business logic. The view models are passed to the views.

Comment: I had started to go down this road however I was unsure of how to join the two tables in my controller.

Comment: I really think this is the way to go, because this answer addresses the problem of mapping a domain model to a view, using a view model. sdm350's answer addresses another issue, how a one-to-one relationship is modeled.

Comment: @Stephen, I don't think there is any magic trick. Just retrieve the two domain models, create a new instance of your view model, and set the properties from each as needed. There may be a more elegant way to accomplish that, but if there is, I don't know it.